# Nested ordered list type not changing in reveal.js

Tags: nested, html-lists, reveal.js

I'm writing a reveal.js project and I can't seem to change the types of the ordered lists.

What I want:

1. Fruits

   a. Orange

   b. Banana

   c. Apple
2. Vegetables

   a. Carrot

   b. Lettuce

   c. Cabbage

I wrote:

`<section>
    <ol type="1">
        <li>
            Fruits
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Orange</li>
                <li>Banana</li>
                <li>Apple</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>
            Vegetables
            <ol type="a">
                <li>Carrot</li>
                <li>Lettuce</li>
                <li>Cabbage</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</section>`

What I get:

1. Fruits

   1. Orange
   2. Banana
   3. Apple
2. Vegetables

   1. Carrot
   2. Lettuce
   3. Cabbage

What am I doing wrong? Is there a restriction in reveal.js that keeps me from changing the types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using a css class to change it instead.

So it now looks like:

```
<style>
    ol.alphaList {list-style-type: lower-alpha;}
</style>

<section>
<ol type="1">
    <li>
        Fruits
        <ol class="alphaList">
            <li>Orange</li>
            <li>Banana</li>
            <li>Apple</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
    <li>
        Vegetables
        <ol class="alphaList">
            <li>Carrot</li>
            <li>Lettuce</li>
            <li>Cabbage</li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```